# Not getting into breakpoints on Aspect in "doSave"

Tags: java, documentum

I have entities who are subtype of dm_folder.
I have a "doSave" (override) function on my aspect, and the aspect is being attached to the type.
A breakpoint exist in the begining of the "doSave" function.
When most of the fields are being changed, the breakpoint is being hit.
When I change the "object_name", especially on change it to a value of other entity, the breakpoint isn't hit.
Why is it happening?
Are there any roles that prevent from getting into "doSave" in some cases?
And if so, how to I edit it?

Comment: What client are you using (Webtop, xCP 1.x, xCP 2.x)? How do you attach aspect to your object? Are you sure it's attached when you change value to the object_name (it is OOTB property)?

Comment: I am using webtop, and the aspect was already attach (when I open the *.type file I can see the aspect there). What do you mean "attached when you change value "? could this be attach only sometimes?

Comment: Yes, you can have business rules to define under which conditions you'll attach aspects. What is *.type file?